# How do I make my AndroidHttpClient preserve cookies between requests?

Tags: java, android, http, cookies

I'm trying to set up a simple app that can log in to a server I run.  I use an `AndroidHttpClient` to send a POST message with the proper credentials, and the server sends back the expected response: a session cookie and a 302 redirect.

For whatever reason, `AndroidHttpClient` doesn't follow that redirect automatically, and trying to get it to do so doesn't seem to work, so I just decided to do so manually:

```
response = client.execute(lPost, myContext);
int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
if (status != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
  headers = response.getHeaders("Location");
  if ((headers != null) && (headers.length > 0)) {
     String newURL = headers[headers.length - 1].getValue();
     response = client.execute(new HttpGet(lPost.URI.resolve(newURL)), myContext);
  }
}
```

The context has previously been set up with a cookie store:

```
myContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, new BasicHttpContext());
```

And yet, when I send the second HTTP request, it comes in to the server without the session cookie!

What am I missing?

Comment: Hmmmm... so long as you are using the same `HttpClient` instance, the cookies should be maintained. It's conceivable that inbound cookies are ignored on redirects -- I have never tried that.

Comment: @CommonsWare: This is `AndroidHttpClient`, which apparently doesn't behave the same as standard `HttpClient`.  For example, there's no way to set a custom redirect handler object (or at least no obvious way), which is what got me into this mess.